# Android Studio changes my keyboard keys around

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to fix the configuration of my keyboard in Android Studio.

When I press:

```
';'
```

Android Studio writes:

```
<
```

All of symbols are changed, I try restart Android Studio to resolve it, but after some minutes change the settings again.

This only happens in the editor of Android Studio. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but on this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows) I found that ALT + LEFT_SHIFT switches between languages in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As [chamanv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6421550/chamanv) said, pressing `ALT + LEFT_SHIFT` switches between languages.
It's windows that's changing your keyboard layout
To change back, just press `ALT + LEFT_SHIFT`

**A more permanent solution:**
To disable this shortcut in windows 10 permanently, Open Settings>Time & Language>Region & Language>Advanced Keyboard Settings>Language Bar Options>Advanced Key Settings
and then click on the `Change key Sequence` button & set the values to `Not Assigned`

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me, and is because android studio is changing your keyboard default language settings, maybe you triggered this by pressing a shortcut.